# Change the backspace behavior in neovim

Tags: vimscript

I have the following function that inserts tabs if cursor is at the start of a line and required amount of spaces otherwise.

```
function! SpecialTab() abort
    if (col('.') == 1) || (matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.(col('.') - 1).'c.') =~ '\t')
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return repeat("\<Space>", (&tabstop - (virtcol('.') % &tabstop) + 1))
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <Tab> SpecialTab()
```

If you use `:set backspace=indent,eol,start` with `:set expandtab`, one backspace can delete a tabs worth of spaces if you originally inserted a tabs worth of spaces by tapping the  key in the first place. But if you manually typed required amount of spaces, one backspace just deletes one space.

I want to get that with my function. I don't have enough experience to understand C source code and I don't understand how backspace characteristics is maintained. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I have just checked that vim actually doesn't check whether the spaces were inserted with pressing `<Tab>` or `<Space>`. It just behaves that way until you escape from the insert mode. After you have escaped from insert mode and returned back to insert mode, if you try to use `<BS>` you'll see that it is deleting `&tabstop` amount (i.e. assuming the spaces are integer multiple of `&tabstop`) of spaces no matter how you inserted it.

Comment: An alternative is to turn on expandtab, return `\<c-v>\<tab>` instead of `\<tab>` .  But i'm afread that will create a new series of problem.

Comment: Do you mean turn on `et` in the function? How would that help? Tabs are not the problem here, I can delete one tab (visualizing `:h ts` worth of spaces) with one backspace key in insert mode. My problem is with deleting tabstop worth of spaces when pressing backspace in insert mode.

Comment: Does setting shiftwidth to the value of tabstop help? What about if you turn on shiftround? What if you use i_CTRL-T and i_CTRL-D instead?

Comment: What if you set smarttab ?

Comment: I have all of `tabstop`, `shiftwidth`, `softtabstop` set to 4 with `smarttab`, `shiftround`, `noexpandtab`. `noet` is necessary for auto-indents and I do use `i_ctrl-t/d` but I want to use <Tab> as the same as `i_ctrl-t` when in first column or after a tab. Everything is working fine except the `<backspace>` which I didn't even notice because I use `i_ctrl-w` anyway. But I needed to unmap <Tab> from my function today and noticed the default behavior. I don't how vim knows whether this set of spaces were inserted with pressing <Tab> and this set of spaces were inserted with <Space>.

Comment: I did some experiment, with non indention space.  During inserting, if you backspace after a series of tab and space (mixed), vim only check the last key stroke, if it's tab, it delete softtabstop number of spaces, other wise only 1 space deleted. If you backspace immediately after enter insert mode,  vim  delete softtabstop number of spaces. I don't believe vim knows if existing space are created by tab or space, it's a bit crazy.

Comment: Is this question actually neovim specific?

Comment: No, should I change the title? I didn't add a tag for `neovim` but absentmindedly mentioned neovim in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discuss only non indention space here.

During inserting, if you backspace after a series of tab and space (mixed), vim only check the last key stroke, if it's tab, it delete softtabstop number of spaces, other wise only 1 space deleted. If you backspace immediately after enter insert mode, vim delete softtabstop number of spaces. I don't believe vim knows if existing space are created by tab or space, it's a bit crazy.

Your backspace behaves different with default because you send 4 space to vim instead of a real tab. To fix that, you must fake a tab by adding an extra tab and backspace after 4 spaces, so vim will believe it's a tab, not space.

```
" vim: tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 smarttab shiftround noexpandtab noet list listchars=tab\:+.,space\:-

function! SpecialTab() abort
    if (col('.') == 1) || (matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.(col('.') - 1).'c.') =~ '\t')
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return repeat("\<Space>", (&tabstop - (virtcol('.') % &tabstop) + 1)) . "\<Tab>\<Backspace>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <Tab> SpecialTab()
```

**update**

I missed something, it's not working.

**update**

for unknow resason send `\<space>\<space>\<space>\<space>\<tab>\<backspace>` will insert a real tab. I have no idea why it behaves like this. But if i send `\<space>\<space>\<space>\<space>a\<tab>\<backspace>\<backspace>`, it works.

```
" vim: tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 smarttab shiftround noexpandtab noet list listchars=tab\:+.,space\:-

function! SpecialTab() abort
    if (col('.') == 1) || (matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.(col('.') - 1).'c.') =~ '\t')
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return repeat("\<Space>", (&tabstop - (virtcol('.') % &tabstop) + 1)) . "a\<tab>\<backspace>\<backspace>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <Tab> SpecialTab()
```

**update**

check comment for the reason why `\<space>\<space>\<space>\<space>\<tab>\<backspace>` result in a tab.

Comment: You function doesn't return space in the else clause. I have copy-pasted it. It just inserts tab characters everywhere.

Comment: I think it's because `"\<Tab>"` converts the previous loose spaces into tabs for some reason. I checked that with vanilla vim and `:set noet` while I tried to insert Tab after `>--->---" hello++` and the text converted to `>---->----" hello>->----`. Here, `>---` are tabs and `+` are spaces.

Comment: fixed. that make sense.

Comment: Hmm. This works as expected. But it's unusual and I would have liked to know why it works like this!

Comment: the "a" after space protect it from tab.

Comment: Also, you might want to change the else statement to this : `return repeat("\<Space>", (&tabstop - (virtcol('.') % &tabstop) + 1))."\<Esc>a"`. It looks much... less confusing, or easier to understand the reason why this change was needed I guess.

Comment: No, I know how your function works. But you have to admit it's unusual practice. I would like to know how `<BS>` actually works. Next time I have time I guess.

Comment: I'm afraid esc  changes dot behavior.

Comment: @klaus some settings will cause vim to convert runs of spaces to tabs when indenting